# Changing column names from monthly to quarterly data (mean value)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe where the two first columns are "Region" and "State" and the next columns are specific months. My goal is to convert the monthly data to quarterly data using the three-month mean.

I have changed my data frame so I keep the first two columns as they are and change the rest of the column names into datetime.

Then I tried to do the same trick but using the "resample function".

```
data.columns = data.columns[:2].tolist()+pd.to_datetime(data.columns[2:], format="%Y-%m").tolist() #keep first two columns, change next two to dateformat

data.columns = data.columns[:2].tolist()+data.columns[2:].resample("Q",axis=1).mean()
```

I get a traceback error stating that "Index" object has no attribute "resample".

Comment: Wellcome to Stackoverflow. please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself (with a little help from another discussion here, which, unfortunately, I have forgot the link to)

I guess the code could be more comprehensive if you are a more experienced python programmer than I am. Feel free to comment!

```
data_new = data.drop(["RegionName", "State"], axis=1) #drop two first columns, keep only dates
data_new.columns = pd.to_datetime(data_new.columns, format="%Y-%m").tolist() #convert to datetime format

#convert to quarterly data using mean, relabel as string
data_new = (data_new.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(data_new.columns, freq="Q"), axis=1).mean().rename(columns=lambda c: str(c).lower()))

data = data.loc[:, ["State", "RegionName"]] #data now only contain first two columns

#merge data and data_new


data_final = pd.merge(data, data_new, left_index=True, right_index=True) #merge data
data_final.set_index(["State", "RegionName"], inplace=True) #set multiindex
```